# Composer on Ubuntu: the same PHP code on 14.04 doesn't wok but on 15.10 work fine

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I've some troubles using composer on Ubuntu 14.04.

Trying this PHP sample code ....

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include "../Utility/SkyScannerJsonPath/vendor/autoload.php";

    $theJson = '{
        "codiciColore": [{
            "id": 2,
            "descrizione": "Giallo",
            "rgb": "FFFF00",
            "priorita": 2,
            "situazionePazienti": {
                "numeroPazienti": 9,
                "numeroPazientiInVisita": 9,
                "mediaAttesa": "00:22",
                "numeroPazientiInAttesa": 0
            }
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "descrizione": "Verde",
            "rgb": "00FF00",
            "priorita": 3,
            "situazionePazienti": {
                "numeroPazienti": 16,
                "numeroPazientiInVisita": 9,
                "mediaAttesa": "03:03",
                "numeroPazientiInAttesa": 7
            }
        }]
   }';

   $jsonObject = new JsonPath\JsonObject();

?>
```

I obtain this error ....

`Fatal error: Class 'JsonPath\JsonObject' not found in /var/www/html/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorso/API/test.php on line 33`

If I try the same code on Ubuntu 15.10 all works fine ...

I've to use Ubuntu 14.04 on my production site ... :-(

I've installed composer on Ubuntu 14.04 following this ...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/736537/installing-composer

.... and trying the command composer from command line it's working fine.

The only difference I can see is about the composer version:

- on Ubuntu 14.04: Composer version 1.6.3
- on Ubuntu 15.10: Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (@package_version@) @release_date@ (quite strange output ... but on this Ubuntu version composer works fine ...)

About the Skyscanner JsonPath implementation (ref. https://github.com/Skyscanner/JsonPath-PHP), and my composer.json is always

```
{"require":{"skyscanner/jsonpath":"dev-master"}}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: under ../Utility/SkyScannerJsonPath/ .... Note for all: the same code works fine on Ubuntu 15.10 ..... same code and same structure project

Comment: if I try to use `require` instead of `include` still I've the same error

Comment: Have a look in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` and see if it matches up with your folder structure.

Comment: This is a good lesson to learn: your development environment should be as similar to your production environment (and your staging environment, and your test environment, etc.) as possible.